# Segue IOS no funciona

Tags: ios, swift3

Qué tal, soy nuevo en swift 3, estoy desarrollando una app utilizando cocoapods, para ser más específico la librería SwipeViewController 0.1.8 y cuando quiero utilizar un segue para cambiar mi escena, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'segue_1''

Mi segue si tiene como identificador "segue_1" tal como en el error se me define, sin embargo mi principal `ViewController` no es subclase de `UIViewController`, sino de "SwipeViewController", que supongo es lo que me genera la excepción, dejo mi código.

```
import UIKit
import SwipeViewController

class ViewController: SwipeViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Uso de SwipeViewController Cocoapods
        let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let page_one   = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page1") as UIViewController
        let page_two   = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page2") as UIViewController
        let page_three = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page3") as UIViewController
        let page_four  = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page4") as UIViewController
        let page_five  = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page5") as UIViewController
        let page_six   = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page6") as UIViewController

        setViewControllerArray([page_one, page_two, page_three, page_four, page_five, page_six])
        setFirstViewController(0)
        setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

        //Uso de SwipeViewController Cocoapods
        //Creación de botones
        let btnNew = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 + 30, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 75, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 35, height: 50))
        btnNew.setTitle("SOY NUEVO", for: .normal)
        btnNew.addTarget(self, action: #selector(soyNuevo), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnNew.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        btnNew.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btnNew.backgroundColor = getColorByHex(rgbHexValue: 0x0071bc, alpha: 1.0)
        btnNew.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 13)
        self.view.addSubview(btnNew)

        let btnCta = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - self.view.frame.size.width + 10, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 75, width: self.view.frame.size.width/2-35, height: 50))
        btnCta.setTitle("YA TENGO CUENTA", for: .normal)
        btnCta.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tengoCuenta), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnCta.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        btnCta.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btnCta.backgroundColor = getColorByHex(rgbHexValue: 0xff5004, alpha: 1.0)
        btnCta.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 13)
        self.view.addSubview(btnCta)
        //Creación de botones
    }

    func soyNuevo(sender: UIButton){
        print("Soy Nuevo")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_1", sender: self)
    }
    func tengoCuenta(sender: UIButton){
        print("Ya Tengo Cuenta")
    }

    func getColorByHex(rgbHexValue:UInt32, alpha:Double = 1.0) -> UIColor {
        let red   = Double((rgbHexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 256.0
        let green = Double((rgbHexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 256.0
        let blue  = Double((rgbHexValue & 0xFF)) / 256.0

        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias por el apoyo, ya quedó resuelto de la siguiente manera:

```
func soyNuevo(sender: UIButton){
    let registro1 = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "registro_1") as! Registro1
    self.present(registro1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Se creó la clase "Registro1", a la que se le asignó el viewController. Agradezco el apoyo y la atención!

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para que sea algo más clara. Siento no haberte dado una respuesta más rápido.

Comment: Descuida, igual tu respuesta amplió mi panorama para encontrar la que funcionó, te agradezco mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Si estás seguro de que el identificador del segue es correcto pero sigue sin funcionar puedes abrir la nueva vista mediante código. Sustituye la línea de "performSegure" por

```
        let ventana = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardID") as UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ventana, animated: false)
```

*editado*
Hay varias formas de presentar un viewController por código y puedes usar la que se ajuste a lo que necesitas

Comment: Que tal! Intenté lo que me recomendaste, y queda así:
func soyNuevo(sender: UIButton){
        let ventana = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "registro_1") as UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ventana, animated: false)
        print("Botón soy nuevo")
    }
Ya no muestra el error, pero ya no hace nada, qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias por contestar!